# python dataset columns are not recognized as numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, numeric, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to read the dataset using python the problem that it does not recognize all the column as numbers
I selected only the 'int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32'data type and it selecte a part of the data

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\thesis\result\15 static\dataset.xls')
data.shape
```

1125x307

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32']
numerical_vars = list(data.select_dtypes(include=numerics).columns)
data = data[numerical_vars]
print (data)
```

1125x50

when I run the code without selecting the numeric value I get this error
and when I add float64 to the numeric value

```
 raise ValueError("Internal work array size computation failed: "
ValueError: Internal work array size computation failed: -10

  warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
```

Comment: Some numeric columns might have been read as strings, you can check them with `data.dtypes`. After that you need to convert them first before using `select_dtypes`

Comment: @Erfan I find out that the problem with float64 when I include it gives me an error I tried to round the data to 4 decimal but it did not work, what should I do?